# Use of Lateral Flatten for JSON in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following JSON as a variant field in snowflake. I get NULLS when querying the data as shown below - -

```
create or replace table car_sales
( 
  src variant
)
as
select parse_json(column1) as src
from values
('{
  "MyData": {
    "DataID": "16784",
    "EmpFirstName": "Jenny",
    "EmpLastName": "Test1",
    "Description": "My Company Data",
    "Assignment": [
      {
        "AssignentId": "1077",
        "AssignentName": "Multi Location",
        "AssignentDescription": "usa",
      },
    ],
    "salary": 21557
  },
  "Update": true
}') v;
```

When I query the data I get Nulls -

```
select value:AssignentId::string as "1ProductName"
from car_sales,
lateral flatten(input => src:Assignment);
```

Output is NULL

Can you help to troubleshoot why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the **MyData** qualifier in the lateral flatten:

```
with car_sales(src) as (
    select
        parse_json(column1) as src
    from
    values
        (
            '{ "MyData": {
     "DataID": "16784",
    "EmpFirstName": "Jenny",
    "EmpLastName": "Test1",
    "Description": "My Company Data",
    "Assignment": [
      {
        "AssignentId": "1077",
        "AssignentName": "Multi Location",
        "AssignentDescription": "usa",
      },
    ],
    "salary": 21557
    }, "Update": true }'
        )
)
select
    value:AssignentId::string as "1ProductName"
from
    car_sales,
    lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);
```

| 1ProductName |
| --- |
| 1077 |

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the child node directly. Specify the parent node as well

```
select value:AssignentId::string as "1ProductName"
from car_sales,
lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);
```

---

```
input => src:Assignment
```

should be

```
input => src:MyData:Assignment
```

Here is the query to read values for each key

```
select  src:MyData.DataID::string as "DataID"
        , src:MyData.EmpFirstName::string as "EmpFirstName"
        , src:MyData.EmpLastName::string as "EmpLastName"
        , src:MyData.Description::string as "Description"
        , value:AssignentId::string as "AssignentId/1ProductName"
        , value:AssignentName::string as "AssignentName"
        , value:AssignentDescription::string as "AssignentDescription"
        , src:MyData.salary::number as "salary"
        , src:Update::boolean as "Update"
from car_sales,
lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);
```

Comment: How do I add additional tags like Update into my query. For example                               
        select value.Update::Boolean as "Update",
    value:AssignentId::string as "1ProductName"
from
    car_sales,
    lateral flatten(input => src:MyData:Assignment);                                                                                 The abouve query gives me an error - unexpected 'Update'.